# Is it possible to do indexed instantiation?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a file that is something similar to:

```
module AB(A,B,Out);
  input A,B;
  output Out;

  wire Out;
  assign Out = A & B;
endmodule
```

I need to use N number of this calculation.
For example, I have a=1001; b=0001, and I need to do something like bitwise AND, and I have N bits.

I have used it as an instantiation:

```
op[0] = a[0] & b[0];
op[1] = a[1] & b[1];
op[2] = a[2] & b[2];
op[3] = a[3] & b[3];
op[4] = a[4] & b[4];
```

When I'm trying to do this with an index i, I have:

```
AB g(a[i],b[i],Op[i]) for i = 0 to N-1.
```

If I do this, it says `AB` is undeclared.

Is this possible? If so, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 8):

You've a few options:

- Parameterise bus sizes in your module
- Array of instances
- `generate` statements

But to answer the question, it is possible to do arrays of instances. Here's what the syntax looks like for your `AB` module.

```
module testbench ();
   localparam WIDTH = 4;

   reg [WIDTH-1:0] a_in, b_in;
   wire [WIDTH-1:0] out_a;

   AB u0[WIDTH-1:0]
     (
      .A(a_in),
      .B(b_in),
      .Out(out_a)
     );

   initial begin
      ...
   end

endmodule
```

Here, `a_in[3]`, `b_in[3]` and `out_a[3]` are mapped to the ports of `u0[3]`.

Comment: and Toolic : Sorry if my question is very stupid. im new to verilog :) I was wondering if I shud write a generate statement, with nested for loops (2 loops), for j=0 to ... and within it i = 0 to... inside the design module; or if I shud write parameterized bus sizes in the test bench. I wud also like to know if i can have 2 d array in the same, like out [j][i].

Comment: i have written the code for the schematic(bitwidth-8) in the slide 19 of the pdf http://www.engr.sjsu.edu/dparent/ee224/adder_verification.pdf im now trying to parameterize it..

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using the `generate` statement which supports an array of instances.  This construct was introduced in the Verilog IEEE Std 1364-2001.

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin
        AB g (a[i], b[i], op[i]);
    end
endgenerate
```