# synthesizable 64 bit full adder in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to design a synthesizable 64 bit full adder, so I need to instantiate the module 64 times, which makes the code bulky. Can anyone suggest an alternative way to minimize the code?

Comment: Use **generate** to minimize your code. Have a look at this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5595254/3951497

Comment: Could you explain why your building a 64 bit adder using a 1 bit adder 64 times?

Comment: Is generate synthesizable?

Comment: @Morgan I wanna design a 64bit full adder. I have created a module for 1bit full adder and calling it in another module.

Comment: @Morgan this approach makes the code very bulky, do you have ways to optimize the code? I want a synthesizable code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your trying to understand structure of gate level design, using synthesizable RTL is much easier:

```
localparam WIDTH = 64;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] a;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] b;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] sum;
always @* begin
  sum = a + b;
end


// to make output sync, put through flip flop
reg [WIDTH-1:0] sum_flop;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  sum_flop <= sum;
end
```

This could be rewritten as the following code but will generate the same hardware.

```
localparam WIDTH = 64;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] a;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] b;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] sum_flop;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  sum_flop <= a + b;
end
```

Comment: I want my full adder to accept the input in the 1st clock pulse, process it and produce the output in the next clock pulse. How can I do it??

Comment: Put sum through a flip flop.